# delivery or a delivery

Tags: articles

I just want to ask a short question. Which is correct 'a delivery' or just 'delivery'? Why they use on ebay etc. 'Special delivery' with no articles?

Comment: You need more context. "A delivery" and "delivery" can be correct depending on the context. _Special_ modifies delivery. So an article is not necessary. _A special delivery_ is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

The noun "delivery" can be used as a countable noun. In that case, you would have to use the indefinite article:

[From Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/delivery):

> [countable]   the process of giving birth to a child [labour]:
>   Mrs Howell had **an** easy delivery.
>   I had only heard horror stories about twin deliveries, but I had **a** good delivery.

In the sense you mentioned, the word "delivery" can be uncountable ("the activity of bringing something"):

> Most Chinese restaurants offer free delivery.

This applies to your "Special delivery" example.

But it also can have the meaning "the goods that are delivered", or "a single act of delivering something", and then it will be countable:

> A buyer or lessee who accepts **a** delivery of goods cannot withdraw the acceptance. ([Google Books](https://books.google.ru/books?id=LSz0c7JoSVwC&lpg=PA150&ots=EZMxEo5MrC&dq=%22a%20delivery%20of%20goods%22&hl=ru&pg=PA150#v=onepage&q=%22a%20delivery%20of%20goods%22&f=false))
>
> This paper makes a comprehensive stylistic analysis of the speech  “I  Have a Dream”  made by Martin Luther King with an attempt to find out how King makes his speech **a** remarkable delivery.

Finally, in short notes on websites like Ebay, in technical instructions and in other contexts where brevity is required an article can be ommitted. [This is also done in newspaper headlines](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38759/dropping-articles-in-the-title-of-an-article-or-a-section-or-in-the-caption-o), and is often referred to as "headlinese" style.